# How to get Google Play Games achievements on games purchased from Amazon AppStore?

Tags: amazon-appstore, google-play-games

I recently purchased Monument Valley from Amazon Appstore, there was a discount. Well, now I want to get achievements in the game, but Play Games achievements are not there because it was not a purchase from Play Store. Is there a way to integrate Play Games achievements to this game ?

Comment: Also interested. The same goes for games from Humble Bundle.

Comment: @Greg, it has been 2 months since the question has been posted, no answers or clues. I guess there is not any workaround for this.

Comment: I asked on XDA, they say that apk file are different on different stores, and only GP ones have Play Games support baked in.

Comment: That's sad :( Can you post the link to XDA discussion ?

Comment: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2997851